Calendar sending early notifications
I have a repeating calendar event with the following details:
Starts: 7/16/2024 6:30 PM
Ends: 7/16/2024 10:00 PM
Repeat: Every Week
End Repeat: Never
Travel Time: 35 minutes
Alert: 10 min before travel

The past 2 weeks, I've gotten a notification at 5:15 PM, even though the notification shouldn't be until 5:45 PM.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Is this an Apple calendar event or one from a third party calendar? I've had some odd notification behaviours with Google calendars synced to Calendar, though not this specific problem. Have you tried completely removing the event and re-adding it? What happens if you create different events and repeating events with travel time alerts?

Are you using 2 alerts?

@BINROTH No, you can see all the settings in the question.

The easiest way is to completely remove the Travel Time and the notification will always show up 10 min before, at 6:20PM.
The notification is influenced by the Travel Time in macOS Sonoma. You can find more details about the Travel Time behaviour in the Apple Support docs.

The time to leave is calculated based on the preference you choose in
the Maps app in the View > Directions menu.
Calendar finds your starting location by using the location in any
events that are up to 3 hours before this event. If Calendar doesn’t
find a location, it uses your work address or home address (from your
card in the Contacts app), depending on the time of day. (Set your
work hours in Calendar General settings using the “Day starts at” and
“Day ends at” pop-up menus.) If your card in Contacts doesn’t have
your addresses, Calendar uses your computer’s current location.
Determining your computer’s location requires that Location Services
be turned on (see Change Privacy settings).
You receive a notification based on your likely location before the
event starts, the event’s location, and current traffic or transit
conditions before you need to leave, when you need to leave, and if
you’re running late.


I don't see how this explains it. Travel time is calculated as 35 minutes. The alert is 10 minutes before travel, so it should be 45 minutes before the event. And I do get an alert at that time, but I also get an extra alert 30 minutes before that.

Did you check the docs? You receive a notification based on your likely location before the event starts, the event’s location, and current traffic or transit conditions before you need to leave, when you need to leave, and if you’re running late.

Not sure why it is necessary to downvote my answer.

So you think that it decided that traffic conditions would add an extra 30 minutes to the travel time? While that might occasionally be possible, this seems to be happening too consistently. It's always exactly 30 minutes before the expected alert time.

FYI, I didn't downvote.

I'm not sure what you mean by "likely location". I'm using my computer at home, the same place where I was when I created the event and calculated the travel time.

I've decided to just get rid of the Travel Time and change the alert to 45 minutes before.

Anyways, I’m glad it worked out and you followed my advice to remove the Travel Time.
